# Rate of Change in surface area

Tags: calculus

> Question: $A$ sunflower grows so that its diameter increases at a
>   constant rate of $0.1$ mm per hour until it reaches $200$ mm.  Find the rate
>   of increase in the surface area of the flower when its diameter is
>   $50$ mm.

How do I get the answer of $7.85 {(\mathrm{mm})^2}$ per hour?

Answer (score 2):

Start with the formula relating its surface area (probably assumed to be the area of a circle) to its diameter. Take the derivative with respect to time, and don't forget the chain rule! Plug in the values you know, and solve for the one you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}=$ Rate of change of surface area.

Let $\color{red}{\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}}=$ Rate of change of radius$=0.05$mm per hour.

We require $\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and by the chain rule $\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}=\color{blue}{\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}r}}\times \color{red}{\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}}$

We already know the value of the part marked red, so we need to find a value for the part marked blue. To do this, we need a connection between the surface area $A$ and the radius $r$.

Can you see what to do next?

> Assuming the sunflower shape is a perfect circle we have $A=\pi r^2\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}r}=2 \pi r$. Insertion of these values into $\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t} \implies \frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}=2\pi r \times 0.05=0.1\pi r$. Now since we want the rate of increase when $r=25$mm: $\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}=0.1\pi \times 25=2.5\pi\approx \color{green}{7.85{(\mathrm{mm})}^2}$ $\color{green}{\mathrm{per}}$ $\color{green}{\mathrm{hour}}$.